# the observeEvent does not react to the render of the list

Tags: r, shiny, render

I have a random word listI want the list to be updated by clicking the "aleatorizar" button.I tried placing the renderprint of the list inside the observerEvent of the click "aleatorizar", but it didn't work.What can I do?

example image below

[image: sample image]

```
server = function(input,output) {
 datatonincanon = reactiveValues(data= NULL)
  
  output$filtrocheck = DT::renderDataTable({
    
    datatonincanon$data = filter(databanco, (databanco$Tonicidade %in% (input$IdTonin) & databanco$Canonicidade %in% (input$IdCanon)))
    DT::datatable(datatonincanon$data[,c(-4,-5,-8,-9,-10,-11,-12,-13)],options = list(searching=TRUE),rownames= FALSE)
    
    })
  
  observeEvent ("IdGerar", {
    
               output$Lista = renderPrint({
                 
                 printf= function(...){
                   invisible(cat(sprintf(...)))
                 }
                 req(datatonincanon$data)
                 data = datatonincanon$data
      printf(as.character(list(sample(data$Palavra, 30))))
           })
               })
```

Comment: Please provide proper tags for your question (e.g. NodeJS, Java, etc...).

Comment: Please change `"IdGerar"` to `input$IdGerar` in the `observeEvent`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so here provide the UI and all packages you use. I think you could use the pattern with a [`eventReactive`](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html#controlling-timing-of-evaluation) that returns the data (and it is reactive on the button click), and then use this reactive object in a `renderPrint`